# In Visual Basic how do I get my First and last name to appear in the Label control?

Tags: vb.net

I have to create a label that displays my first and last name from the paragraph below but is doesn't appear to be working and I am not receiving an ERROR messages.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub lblName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblName.Click


        Dim strName As String = "Principles As a leading institution of higher education, Rio Salado College strongly promotes core principles and values of Academic Ethics and Integrity. We believe in the central importance of ethical values and academic character virtues in achieving academic excellence. It is the duty and responsibility of all Rio Salado faculty, students, employees, clients, and partners to support ethical principles and values and to incorporate them into all practices of our core college principles of learning, innovating, and partnering. As a foundation for all other ethical values, Rio Salado College is committed to excellence. We support high standards of quality and ethical behavior, pursued and practiced with diligence, conscientiousness, and discipline. We expect the best from ourselves and value the necessary human effort and courage, often in the face of adversity, in realizing our highest ideals. Since becoming an educated person or a valuable employee is a personal accomplishment and achievement, we expect self-responsibility and accountability. As a core character virtue, self-responsibility empowers and motivates the learner and is the foundation of all meaningful achievements. Further, self-responsibility is necessary for mutual trust and dependability. Self-responsibility entails that we are held accountable for our actions and accept the appropriate consequences for our behavior. As a center of learning and study, we critically value the pursuit of truth; further, we value truth as a necessary foundation for trust among us. Hence, we esteem honesty, integrity, and authenticity as character virtues in our institution, and we do not tolerate anything less. Through a number of ongoing institutional practices, we monitor and verify the integrity and authenticity of student assignments. In order to secure and maintain our public trust with the community, we understand that honesty and integrity are critical. In our interactions with everyone, we strive for fairness and justice. Our judgments and our behaviors rest upon treating each other equitably and impartially. We are open to hearing and thoughtfully assessing each person’s perspective on an issue. Actions are judged and rewarded on their merits. Consistent with our core value of inclusiveness, we believe in and practice social civility and mutual respect. We have compassion and concern for everyone, and maintain a social conscience regarding the human and environmental consequences of everything we do.Finally, as an educational institution, we believe that the life-long acquisition of knowledge, the development of critical thinking skills, and ongoing critical self-reflection are essential to the realization of a productive and meaningful life. We believe that maintaining a sense of wonder and curiosity and the love of learning and thinking are essential for personal and institutional growth. Ultimately, we value wisdom: the ethical and thoughtful application of broadly-based knowledge for the benefit of oneself and others. "


        Dim intPosition As Integer

        Dim strT As String = CStr(CInt(intPosition.ToString()))
        For intCount = 1 To 12


        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("M")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("a")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("r")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("g")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("a")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("r")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("e")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("t")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("P")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("e")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("r")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("e")
        intPosition = strName.IndexOf("z")

        Next

        lblName.Text = strT

  End Sub
```

Comment: Umm, Margaret, is it because that text does not actually contain your name?  Question shows a serious lack of understanding of basic coding principles too.

Comment: Where do add your name ?

Comment: I am suppose to pull letters that create my name and these letters come together on the Form in a label

Comment: You need to click on the label to see the result. You should really read everything line by line and understand what each variable are containing at each lines.

Answer (score 1):

You set strT just once, before the for loop and then at the end you just set its value on the label.... you never changed the value of the string in the loop.